# Access a job's failed logs in a Github Action?

Tags: github-actions, github-api, github-cli

I want to automatically create a Github issue with an action if a job fails. In this issue, I want to include the log in the issue body but I can't figure out how to get this log.

I've tried using the Github CLI `gh run view --log-failed --job <jobID>`. However, this requires the job ID, which is tough to impossible to get for a matrix job. I've tried [this action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-actions-job_id-parser), but my matrix uses a stringified JSON matrix value which creates a truncated job name so this doesn't solve the problem reliably. Also, when trying this command locally, I receive an empty response with the `--log` or `--log-failed` flags.

I am currently creating the issue in the same job as the failing one using `if: ${{ failure() }}`.

Any tips or ideas for how I can auto-create an issue containing job failure logs in the body? Too many yaks are getting shaved.

Comment: Maybe explicitly write the log to a file with `tee` and upload it as an asset before failing?

Comment: Thanks. I resorted to swapping out the `uses` steps with `run` and using tee. Not the most elegant solution, but I've really reached the limitations of Github Actions trying to do this.